# How to fix issue RestControllerAdivse not working?

Tags: spring-boot

I have an issue related to RestControllerAdvice.
I have built an internal jar file as my own library and I implement some exception handler.
Anyway, that RestControllerAdvice is not working when have throw exception error.

1. RestControllerAdvice

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ApiControllerHandler {
   @ExceptionHandler(ApiException.class)
   public @ResponseBody
   ApiResponse handleApiRequestException(ApiException e) {
       ApiResponse response = new ApiResponse();
       response.setCode(e.response.getCode());
       response.setMessage(e.response.getMessage());
       return response;
   }
}
```

2. validator method

```
    public static void request(JSONObject jsonReq, String requestKey) throws ApiException{
        if (requestKey.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ApiException("01", "Please input request validate key");
        }
        String key = jsonReq.getString(requestKey);
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(key)) {
            throw new ApiException("01", requestKey + " Can not be null or empty.");
        }
    }
```

3. RestController

```
  @PostMapping("/")
   public String index(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> map){
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(map);
       SPNValidator.request(jsonObject, "username");
       return "Hello";
   }
```

4. Request

```
{
   "username" : ""
```

When post this request, exception will be throw because I already handled request not empty nor null
but my restControlleradvise is not working, it throws internal exception error.

Note: it works as normal if i use the same project,
but when build as jar file for other use, this function not work.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible reason

- When you build as internal JAR at that time spring dosen't know about any class in JAR so it will not search any package/Class from jar file so that's why your `@RestControllerAdvice` from internal JAR is not working

To solve this please use your internal JAR pacakge name in `@ComponentScan`
like below

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.exception.base"})
```

so spring will inlcude `ApiControllerHandler` while scanning you project file.